# Laravel: Artisan serve and SASS

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-artisan

**Question.** How can I run Laravel and have my sass autocompiled when changes are made?

**Problem.** At the moment I run Laravel with artisan serve. But I have to stop the artisan every time i need to run gulp (to compile the sass). 
I guess this is a newbie problem, but I have not found an answer to it yet.

**Background.** I am using a local project on my Windows(10) computer, Laravel (v. 5.2), Composer, laravel-elixir and gulp. The gulp command works, but only if I stop the artisan serve "loop".

**gulpfile.js**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir'); 
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
});
```

**Edit.** I guess my question is this: can I serve Laravel with gulp somehow, or perhaps combine artisan serve with gulp somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way out of the box to run serve and gulp watch at the same time. What you could do is run a shell command while watching the sass files. How do you do that? You should use [Gulp-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-exec) and extend the sass task from the laravel gulp file, as said [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir#extensions).

Comment: Thanks, I might check that solution. But I keep wondering, what others use to serve Laravel, and still use gulp, on local machine. Do they use XAMPP or MAMP etc for this perhaps?

Comment: Yes, the most common "container" for a laravel app are apache (mamp or xampp) and ngix.

Answer (score 3):

Just run `gulp watch` in another tab

From the docs: "This command will continue running in your terminal and watch your assets for any changes. When changes occur, new files will automatically be compiled"

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#running-elixir

Comment: I would not recommend the `gulp watch` command, as every task will run anytime any file being watched changes. This may add a ton of time. If you just need `sass` to be recompiled, then only run `gulp watch sass`. Otherwise, move the `sass` tasks to the top of the gulp file, so that they at least run first.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to execute `gulp watch sass`. The `.sass()` method extended from the `.mix` is actually a `task name` that gulp recognizes.

You can also gulp all the other default mixins

```
gulp watch styles
gulp watch scripts
```

And so on and so forth.

Comment: Forgive me if I understand you wrong. But if I run "gulp watch sass" it wont run the Laravel project (I use the "artisan serve" command-"loop" to run it). It just says "starting watch", and on third line "Finished watch". I cant enter a new command until I break the "loop" (or what to call it).